# Which files deploy when I deploy a single function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Let's say I have 10 functions and my structure is;

```
func1
|___index1.js
|___sum.js (imported in index1.js)
|___divide.js (imported in the index1.js)
func2
|___index2.js
|___makeSound.js (imported in index2.js)
|___makeMove.js (imported in index2.js)
| And so on...
| so on...
| so on...
```

And in this structure, all the files are imported in their index.ts files and to deploy a single function I'm using `firebase deploy --only functions:func1` but when I deploy **only func1** do sum.js and divide.js files are deploy with it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Please edit the question to be more clear.  The phrase in the title "deploy a single function into multiple functions" doesn't make sense.  I suggest rephrasing your question in terms of behavior that you observe that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Please describe the mechanism you build an deploy the functions. You could package them together and deploy together or do it for each of them separately.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I've made it more understandable. I hope this better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All** files in the top-level "functions" folder will are sent with every deployment, with the exception of node_modules, which will be rebuilt based on the contents of your package.json.  There is no "tree-shaking" or any sort of algorithm that attempts to figure out which files are absolutely necessary.